# AWS C# Lambda times out trying to issue the connection.Open command using Snowflake.Data

Tags: aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timeout, database-connection

I have an AWS Lambda written in C# attempting to connect to Snowflake. The connection works intermittently.

Based on logging, Snowflake.Data will issue the `Open()` command but never gets a response—eventually, the Lambda times out.

Observations:

- When able to connect to Snowflake, performance is great. There appear to be now delays, just on or off.
- Sometimes, the connection will work if I wait a lot between requests. But then it will eventually stop working again.
- I switched from Snowflake.Data (https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net) to Snowflake.Client (https://github.com/fixer-m/snowflake-db-net-client). I modified the Snowflake.Client to add detailed logging. The time out occurs in the `AuthenticateAsync` method. The HTTP Client will initiate the connection, but a response is never returned.
- Adjusting the Lambda's configuration (e.g., slightly adjusting the time out) or republishing the Lambda with the same code will occasionally fix the connection issue.

Other Details:

- The Lambda is on a VPC to access other AWS resources. The Security Group configuration will allow all inbound and outbound traffic.
- The Snowflake instance is not configured to block any requests
- The Snowflake logs show only successful login and queries. It does not show these login attempts that never return a response.